# XSD for this type of XML: Attribute based substructure

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

```
<item type="A">
<subitem attra="" attrb=""></subitem>
<subitem attra="" attrb=""></subitem>
</item>
<item>
<subitem></subitem>
<subitem></subitem>
</item>
```

So when item is of type "A" then only subitem will have attributes, else they should be optional.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional validation is not supported in XML Schema 1.0. Check [RELAX NG](http://www.relaxng.org/), [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/), or [XSD 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) for options.